# MD5 algorithm to hash passwords with salt

Tags: java, mysql, hash, md5, salt

Why does getBytes[ ] and insert bytes[ ] give different results ?

### Database: Table Definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  `username` VARCHAR(15),
  `password` VARCHAR(32),
  `salt`     VARCHAR(32)
);
```

Whenever I want to make a new user , I produce a random salt (type: bytes[ ]) and then store it on the database along with the other columns .

But , when I try to retrieve the salt from the db using `rs.getBytes("Salt")` I won't get the same result.

I know that I can retrieve the salt with `rs.getString("Salt")` BUT I need to get it as `byte[]` type.

I tried to cast the `String` to `Bytes[]` but again not the same results..!!

### Code: Insert into Database

```
String username = "admin";
String password = request.getParameter("password"); 
byte[] salt = SaltedMD5.getSalt(); 
password = SaltedMD5.getSecurePassword(password, salt); 
stmt.executeUpdate(String.format("INSERT INTO users VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')", username, password, salt));
```

### Output: Query Result

```
byte[] DB_salt = rs.getBytes("Salt");
```

Comment: You really, really need to learn about [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Your query inserts the toString representation of a byte array, which always looks like [B@12435, i.e. the type followed by a hashCode. Also, don't store bytes in a varchar column. EIther use a binary type, or use base64 to transform your byte array into a printable string.

Comment: Please please forget about MD5 for hashing passwords, it is ways too fast and can be brute-forced too easily ([100 Giga MD5 per second](http://hashcat.net/hashcat/#performance)). Instead switch to BCrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: Prepared statements don't seem to help ..
Should i use rs.getBytes("Salt") to get the salt from the db ?

Comment: If i store the salt as a String it works , but i can't convert byte[ ] to String .
Any ideas ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and switch to a secure algorithm. Not only will your passwords be protected properly, you also don't have to care about generation and storage of the salt.

Most [BCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) implementations will include the generated salt as part of the resulting hash, so you need only a single field for password hashes with a minimum length of `varchar(60)`.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
String hashToStoreInDb = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from existingHashFromDb.
Boolean isPasswordCorrect = BCrypt.checkpw(password, existingHashFromDb);
```